# Estimating the autocorrelation function with some noisy observations

Tags: autocorrelation, white-noise, variogram

I am wondering how to estimate the actual correlation function when I have some noisy samples of some space. Lets say, I have a space and the locations in the space are variables following a multivariate gaussian distribution. I generate some samples with the given autocorrelation function and add some noise independently to all of them.

Now from the samples I find an empirical correlation function and then fit a model autocorrelation function to it. This model might has some nugget effects or might not represent the true autocorrelation function. How to deal with this issue?

For eg, I generated some data with exponential correlation function with range 10. If I add no noise and try to fit a model correlation function(exponential) based upon some samples of the field. I get almost the actual function.

I generated data with exponential correlation function with range 10. I then got some samples from this function. I got the empirical correlation function and then fit a model (exponential) to it to get almost the same params i.e range of 9.5

However, when I add some white gaussian noise to the correlation/covariance function(I assume std to be 1) and then I tried to fit a model correlation function to the empirical one, I got range of 5 and also nugget of 0.8. How to estimate the underlying function in this case?